# Group-Object folder by folder for deletion

Tags: powershell

I have a copyscript that copies QVD files from a QlikView structure, which was fine for one enviroment, now in the second one the file structure is much more complex and I can't use the same groupcode for grouping the files before deleting them.

Below you will see the code for case one that works.

I tried a few version with `-Include`, `-Exclude`, `-Recurse`, `-Properties basename`, directory, etc. without any progress.

```cs
$global:currenttime = Set-PSBreakpoint -Variable currenttime -Mode Read -Action { $global:currenttime= Get-Date }
$a = Get-Date
$a.ToUniversalTime()
$date = Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd
$LocalPath = "d:\QlikView Storage\PrivateData\"

Get-ChildItem *.qvd -Path "D:\QlikView Storage\PrivateData\" -File -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) } |
    Select-Object Name, @{Name="KBytes";Expression={"{0:N0}" -f ($_.Length / 1KB)}} |
    Export-Csv C:\temp\size\$date.qvdsize1.csv

"Kopiering av folders startad $global:currenttime" | Out-File F:\Log\$date.log.txt -Append

Get-ChildItem -Directory $localpath -Recurse -Verbose | Where {
    $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
} | foreach {
    $split = $_.FullName -split '\\'
    $DestFile = $split[1..($split.Length - 1)] -join '\'
    $DestFile = "F:\$DestFile"
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $DestFile)) {  
        Copy-Item -Path $_.Fullname -Destination $destfile -Filter {psicontainer} -Recurse -Verbose 4>&1 |
            Out-File -Append F:\Log\$date.log.txt
    }
}

"Kopiering av folders slutförd $global:currenttime" | Out-File F:\Log\$date.log.txt -Append
"Kopiering av filer påbörjad $global:currenttime" | Out-File F:\Log\$date.log.txt -Append

Get-ChildItem -File  "*.qvd" $localpath -Recurse -Verbose | Where {
    $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
} | foreach {
    $split = $_.FullName -split '\\'
    $DestFile = $split[1..($split.Length - 1)] -join '\'
    $DestFile = "F:\$DestFile"
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $DestFile)) {  
        Copy-Item -Path $_.Fullname -Include "*.qvd" -Destination "$destfile.$(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd)" -Filter {PSIsContainer} -Recurse -Verbose 4>&1 |
            Out-File -Append F:\Log\$date.log.txt
    }
}
"Kopiering av filer avslutad  $global:currenttime" | Out-File F:\Log\$date.log.txt -Append
 "Börjar borttagninvg av äldre generation $global:currenttime" | Out-File F:\Log\$date.log.txt -Append

$Groups = Get-ChildItem -Path "F:\qlikview Storage\privatedata\" -Recurse |
          Group-Object -Property BaseName |
          Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 2}
foreach ($g in $Groups) {
    $g.Group |
        sort LastWriteTime -Descending |
        select -Skip 2 |
        foreach {del $_.FullName -Force -Verbose 4>&1} |
        Out-File -Append F:\Log\$date.log.txt
}
"Klar med borttagninvg av äldre generation $global:currenttime" | Out-File F:\Log\$date.log.txt -Append
```

The folder structure is quite long, so one folder can contain twenty subfolders, and files in folder 1 and 18 in one chain under d:\QlikView Storage\PrivateData\ can contain files with same name.

So when grouping objects, it has do it folder by folder only, so if folder 1 and subfolder contains objects with same name they still have to be grouped diferently.

In the picture below you see one ap as an example, and some subfolders in that contain .QVD files, then subfodlers to subfolders can contain .QVD files as well.

This should make it more clear.

[image]

Comment: What... is the expectation here? That we guess the correct folder structure and appropriate grouping logic and implement your new script?

Comment: I did not create a dummy structure to show you, thats why I wrote, it varies from one to 20 subfolders for each application, and that they may contain the name.

The expection is how, I can rewrite my group-object so it does it folder for folder instead, as when it comes to lets say subfolder one it will only group for that folder and then repeat through the whole structure. I can add a img of how it looks if that helps. 

PS. Sorry if I don't make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem this morning after an intrestring dream about it.

The code below fixes it.

```
$Groups = Get-ChildItem -Path "d:\qlikview Storage\privatedata\" -Recurse  |
        Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
        Group-Object -Property basename, directory |
        Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 2}
foreach ($g in $Groups) {
    $g.Group |
        sort LastWriteTime -Descending |
        select -Skip 2 |
        foreach {del $_.FullName -Force -Verbose 4>&1} |
        Out-File -Append D:\Log\$date.log.txt
```